# Regex to find text not preceded by any other non-space character(s) on line

Tags: regex, matlab, octave

I am looping through lines in a text file, and want to detect a line of text like this:

```
See Also: something.m, something_else.m
```

The key thing is the `See Also` part

1. `See Also` is case insensitive
2. `See Also` can be preceded by whitespace
3. `See Also`can be followed by whitespace
4. `See Also` must not preceded by any other non whitespace text, for example  I want `foobar blahblah See Also` to fail to match. I dont want there to be anything on the line before `See Also` except whitespace
5. `See Also` can optionally be followed by a semicolon ':' then more whitespace
6. `See Also`, or `See Also:` or `See Also  :` etc. can can optionally be followed by more text after the whitespace provided there is at least one whitespace character after the 'o' or ':'

I have most of the regex, the problem is detecting if there is text preceding `See Also`. Below is my attempt (in matlab/Octave code). However, it supports standard regular expressions (as far as I know) including lookahead and lookbehind.

```
[start_idx, end_idx, extents, match] = ...
    regexp ('See Also ', '(?<!\S*)\s*See\sAlso\s*[:]?\s*(\s[A-Za-z0-9_\.]*)?\s*$', 'ignorecase', 'once')
```

So the actual regex attempt is

```
(?<!\S*)\s*See\sAlso\s*[:]?\s*(\s[A-Za-z0-9_\.]*)?\s*$
```

The above fails to match `See Also` can anyone suggest the problem?

Comment: You can't have `*` inside of a lookbehind. You can also use `^` to enforce it at the beginning of the string, which eliminates the cases where it's preceded by text.

Comment: @excaza, thanks ctwheels came up with an answer which doesn't even require lookbehind (very quickly too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern below uses `mi` flags (on top of global `g` flag)

[See code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/MGSaPJ/2)

```
^[ \t]*see also[ \t]*:?[ \t]+(.*)
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[ \t]*` Match any number of spaces or tab characters
- `see also` Match this literally (`i` flag for case-insensitivity matches uppercase variants of the letters in the pattern)
- `[ \t]*` Match any number of spaces or tab characters
- `:?` Optionally match `:` literally
- `[ \t]+` Match one or more spaces or tab characters
- `(.*)` Capture any character any number of times into capture group 1

#### Edit

As pointing out in the comments, the string `see also :something.m, something_else.m` should not be caught by the pattern (missing space after colon). The pattern below corrects this issue.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/MGSaPJ/4)

```
^[ \t]*see also(?:[ \t]*:)?+[ \t]+(.*)
```

- `(?:[ \t]*:)?+` Optionally match without giving up matches as the engine backtracks (possessive)

Comment: So fast! The only flaw is that it should not match, for example `see also :something.m, something_else.m`, there should be a space after colon

Comment: @crobar fixed. I added a new line of code that uses the possessive `q+` quantifier mode (where `q` is a quantifier) - see the 9th line in the second link to see it in action.

Comment: Nice, thanks, took me longer to understand why the original actually matched `see also :something.m, something_else.m`.

Comment: @crobar took me a second too, but it's due to `.*` appearing after `[ \t]+`, which, itself, appears after two conditional subpatterns: `[ \t]*:?`. Regular expression engines *want* to match something, and since `[ \t]+` matches and so does `(.*)` (this group starting at `:`) it gave us a positive match.

Comment: @Downvoter not sure why this was downvoted, it works and was even chosen as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you can not have a [quantifier in the negative lookbehind](https://regex101.com/r/OA8goc/1).

You could add a whitespace and a comma to your character class and replace `[A-Za-z0-9_]` with `\w`.

For example:

[`^\s*See\sAlso\s*:?\s*(\s[\w., ]*)?\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/uFUea8/1)

Comment: thanks, the `\w` tip is useful as are the other pioints